# Find the point of intersection of line $r=(3,7,1)+n(0,2,4)$ with the plane containing only $x-axis$ and $z-axis$.

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry, parametrization

Find the point of intersection of line $r=(3,7,1)+n(0,2,4)$ with the plane containing only $x-axis$ and $z-axis$.

**My Working:**

The parametric representation of the the given line is: $x=3$, $y=7+2n$, $z=1+4n$.

Now I don't know how do I get the equation of plane from the information that "the plane contains only $x-axis$ and $z-axis.$" Once I know the equation of plane I know how to answer the question. Please guide me how do I find it.

Comment: The plane that contains the $x$ axis and $z$ axis is the plane $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate that but I already know it, it's obvious. Still The equation of plane is something I can't seem to figure out, I don't even know where to begin.  Give me a hint at least where do I start?

Comment: The equation in the comment is the equation of the plane.

Comment: hahaha. That was right there in front me. I didn't pay attention. Thanks a lot. Now I just need to plug the value of $y$ to get $n$ and then plugging value of $n$ in $x$, $y$, $z$ gives the point of intersection